# Ubuntu Belgian eid reader

Tags: hardware

What devices can be used as card readers for the Belgian ID card so they work in Ubuntu?
There are a couple of questions on this topic but only about driver installation.

Comment: Which interface it has? Is it USB? If yes, please connect reader and share output of `lsusb`.

Comment: It is a USB device, yes. But there are a few models available, I haven't found any that officially support Linux